# k-means clustering with survival Data

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, survival-analysis

just a basic question concerning k-means clustering analysis on survival data, like this one:

[image]

I am doing k-means clustering to identify clusters which Gene influences the survival most... However do I include the survival time into my k-means function or should I leave it out? So should I put it into the kmeans() function e.g. in R?

Kind regards,

Hashriama

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your approach is not the best one. Your goal is to select genes associated with censored/uncensored survival. The use of **supervised** methods seems the most suitable. Using a k-means will only cluster genes by similarities without regard to survival, and even if you wanted to add survival in your modeling it would not make sense because you are omitting censoring.

There are Cox regressions to which an L1 penalty is added, allowing variable selection without omitting censoring. This kind of approach seems more appropriate to accomplish your goal and fits better in your context. To learn more, here is an article from Jiang Gui & Hongzhe Li that uses penalized Cox regression (look at the R package **biospear** too if needed):
*https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/21/13/3001/196819*

Comment: Thanks gdrouard for your quick and very helpful answer! The biospear R package looks really great. I have already tried Cox PH Model and Random Survival Forest as supervised methods. However, I was really interested to use unsupervised methods just to find distinct gene clusters. I thought about maybe a descision tree or hierarchical clustering. And then I want to see if the found clusters using unsupervised learning methods correlates with the survival. So I can say that a distinct cluster of genes has impact on the survival... Maybe I can use decision trees, hierarchical clustering, ...?

Comment: Dear Hashriama,
I understand your objective a little better. If you want to do unsupervised at all costs, then you can indeed do unsupervised classification on the genes to get gene groups. Classification methods such as k-means or hclust can be interesting as you mention, but be sure to find out the limits of each of these algorithms on high dimensional data (e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93488/usefulness-of-k-means-clustering-on-high-dimensional-data). Once your groups are made, you could eventually consider each cluster as a variable by using the barycenter of each class.

Comment: Thus, for k classes you would have k variables to test on survival. In the end, you will be forced to do supervised testing. The choice of the number of classes is crucial in your case: a too low number of classes will annihilate the information and you will not find any link between your classes and the global survival.

Comment: This is not the method I would have chosen but I guess it is possible. If you have done supervised learning before, it would be interesting to compare your results with each method. Honestly, I don't think you will find better results than with a supervised method. I hope I have answered your questions. My opinion is by no means absolute and you are free to interpret it. Sincerely